# Reference question/answer for Kali Linux questions

Tags: discussion, flagging

Is there a reference question such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me/399627#399627) on SU?

On U&L, questions on Kali (especially all those about network connectivity) are flagged as duplicate of this one.

Comment: I sometimes refer a user that seems like they are in over their head to this: https://kali.training/downloads/Kali-Linux-Revealed-1st-edition.pdf it's from the developers, and is meant for newbies and experts as a reference. Do we really want that for SU? They close almost **every Kali** question with very troll like behavior. Also that post over at U&L is contradictory to what the developers say.

Comment: You mean, contradictory with *To get the most out of Kali, it is important to have a thorough understanding of its powerful Debian GNU/Linux underpinnings* (see "Introduction" page) and *Kali is aimed at security professionals and IT administrators* (page 11)?

Comment: i was referring to "Whether you’re new to Information Security, or a seasoned security veteran, the Kali Linux Revealed Book and our online training exercises have something to teach you. The saying “You can’t build a great building on a weak foundation” rings true in the information security field as well, and if you use (or want to learn to use) Kali Linux in a professional capacity, you should familiarize yourself as best as you can with the internals of the penetration testing distribution." from https://kali.training/

Comment: but yes, even that statement from kali training seems to contradict the manual they created. either way, the manual covers "questions about network connectivity". its the users responsibility to make sure that their NICs / Adapters are compatible with the version they are using. if they are not, the user can use that guide to make a custom image for themselves.

Comment: OK, so "RTFM" is going to be a boilerplate answer :)

Comment: lol, maybe not with the Fing. even the "I tried to update "x" package and now my installation is broken" type questions are covered in the manual. Honestly why would we help someone who is not willing to take the time to learn / read about the distro? pointing them in the right direction is better IMO than saying "The reason for x is that you are using x distribution". it feels a little esoteric to me.

Comment: A passive/agressive answer is to create a question "Is there a Kali documentation" with the URL as an answer and flag Kali questions as duplicates of that :)

Comment: @xenoid - Any comment or answer that contains the phrase "RTFM", will be reported to a moderator, don't use that phrase here.  It's offensive and rude.  Likewise an answer, that points to another answer on another SE community, will be flagged for moderator attention.  Link-only answers are not acceptable.  In both cases, unhelpful answers, will be downvoted.

Comment: I usually comment: *If you're asking this question then Kali is probably not for you*.